# how shared_buffers works when we update a table in postgres

Tags: postgresql, rdbms, postgresql-9.3

Say i have to update a table in postgres that is of size 10gb and my shared_buffers is 1 gb, can you explain the working if the update is committed and update fails after a certain period.

Comment: https://2ndquadrant.com/media/pdfs/talks/InsideBufferCache.pdf